# Zariski topology on $\mathbb{P^n}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, path-connected, zariski-topology

I want to prove or disprove that the open sets of the **Zariski topology** on $\mathbb{P^n}$ are **path-connected**.
Here $\mathbb{P^n}$ is the complex projective n-space.
Thanks for any hint or answer.

Comment: I am confused as to why you added more context to [your closed question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4797493) and then instead of asking for it to be reopened asked the same question again without the context.

Comment: Do not re-ask a closed question. Instead, improve your closed question so it can be reopened.